# Solve for $a$: $V=2(ab+bc+ca)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve for $a$
>   $V=2(ab+bc+ca)$

$$\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)=ab+bc+ca$$ $$\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)-bc=ab+ca$$ $$\dfrac{\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)-bc}{b+c}=2a$$ $$\frac{\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)-bc}{2b+c}=a??$$ I honestly do not know what to do with this problem. And I think I may have messed up when I divided by $b+c$. Any pointers. please, no answers. Only generalized hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$V=2(ab+ac+bc)$$

$$\frac{V}{2} = (ab+ac+bc)$$

Note that two terms on the RHS have an $a$ term, so we can factor them and rewrite it as:

$$\frac{V}{2} = a(b+c) + bc$$

$$\frac{V}{2} - bc = a(b+c)$$

I rewrote the LHS so it is easier to see the step when dividing through by $b+c$:

$$\frac{1}{2}(V - 2bc) = a(b+c)$$

Divide through by $b+c$ to get:

$$a = \frac{V-2bc}{2(b+c)}$$
for $b+c \ne 0$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}(V - 2bc) = a(b+c)$ where did that $2bc$ come from?

Comment: Note that $\frac{V}{2} - bc = \frac{1}{2}(V-2bc)$ because $\frac{1}{2}\cdot2bc = bc$. I was just trying to make it easier to see the simplified answer. There are other forms of the correct expression for $a.$

Comment: I made a LaTeX error, I had edited it. Sorry. Based on your work, your error is in the second to third line. Once you have 

$$\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)-bc=ab+ca$$, you can factor an $a$ term out on the RHS and you get my expression for $a.$

Comment: I always make errors. No big deal. And I see, since it would become, $\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{2bc}{1}=\dfrac{2bc}{2}$ and the twos would cancel.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Everyone makes mistakes - it helps when others can point you in the right direction and you can learn!

Comment: Indeed! I'm fairly new to this site and completely new to LaTeX. Still learning the ropes over here! But thanks for the cooperation. I think I have understanding of the problem

Comment: Glad to hear it. Don't worry, you'll get a hang of the LaTeX. Feel free to click the "edited _ minutes ago" to learn the code. I remember, as do others, our first time on the site trying to eagerly learn as others marked up our posts.

Comment: quick question. How would I write, in LaTeX, a plus or minus symbol. Not either or. I mean like if you take $\sqrt{4}$ you get $-2$ and $2$. How would you write that with one symbol.

Comment: Use \pm and enclose it with dollar signs.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You are on the right track, but you did make an error. Try doing the step when you divided by $b+c$ backwards.

Comment: By backwards, do you mean multiply? I tried individually dividing $b$ and $c$. and got: $$\left(\frac{V-bc}{2cb}\right)=a$$

Comment: By backwards, I mean take your expression $\dfrac{\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)-bc}{b+c}=2a$ and multiply it by $b+c$. Do you get the expression you had before you divided by $b+c$?

Comment: No, you get; $\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)-bc=2a(b+c)$. But that doesn't help solve for $a$ because you would have to divide by $b+c$ anyway to get it unattached from the $a$.

Comment: Since you did that one step forwards and then backwards and got something different, you know that you did something wrong there.

If you distribute your $2a$ in what you just wrote, you get $\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)-bc=2ab+2ca$. This is very close to what it should be, but the right is a bit different - there's an extra factor of $2$ on each term. That should tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Okay, so $2ab+2ca$, can I take out the a, since it is in both and get, $a(2b+2c)$. And then divide that by the $a$ and get a final answer of; $\dfrac{\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)-bc}{2b+2c}=a$?

Comment: Not quite; perhaps I've not explained my hint clearly. Try it this way: I see you refer to "take out the a". Do this from your (correct) expression $\left(\frac{V}{2}\right)-bc=ab+ca$.